# How can i get alert when a new post get added to an Instagram profile?

Tags: notifications, comments, instagram, automation

because Instagram doesn't  have the bell option .. 
i don't if it's possible using (js or vbs ) .. if there isn't a way to do this without letting my pc turned on the whole day ...
i do need to make it comment automatically when the post gets added .
i want it to alert or comment when the posts number get's increased.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUFD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Instagram has an API that you can use that might suite your needs. It should work in whatever language you want to use as long as it has the ability to consume an API.

https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Any questions about how to use a language to query the API would need to be posted on StackOverflow and not here.